# Customizing a Api Platform POST Json request

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

the schema and json request right that api platform generated for me is wrong, the dossier entity has a relationship with the fase, type and status entity so when making a new dossier the fase, type and status entity get connected by id's to each the dossier entity, but right the schema generated is wrong the fase has a title field which i wanna post not literally the fase object same with the other 2 entities

MY DOSSIER ENTITY

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Common\Filter\SearchFilterInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Common\Filter\DateFilterInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\DateFilter;
use Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Fase;

#[ApiResource(normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['dossier']])]
#[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['deleted_at' => DateFilterInterface::INCLUDE_NULL_AFTER])]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['title' => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_PARTIAL, 'created_at' => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_PARTIAL])]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Dossier
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('dossier')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups('dossier')]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    #[Groups('dossier')]
    private ?int $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    #[Groups('dossier')]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $created_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups('dossier')]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $updated_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true, options: ['default' => null])]
    #[Groups('dossier')]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $deleted_at = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Fase::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['dossier', 'dossier:write'])]
    private ?Fase $fase = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Type::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['dossier', 'dossier:write'])]
    private ?Type $type = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: DossierStatus::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['dossier', 'dossier:write'])]
    private ?DossierStatus $dossier_status = null;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(int $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deleted_at;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $deleted_at): self
    {
        $this->deleted_at = $deleted_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFase(): ?Fase
    {
        return $this->fase;
    }

    public function setFase(?Fase $fase): self
    {
        $this->fase = $fase;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?Type
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?Type $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDossierStatus(): ?DossierStatus
    {
        return $this->dossier_status;
    }

    public function setDossierStatus(?DossierStatus $dossier_status): self
    {
        $this->dossier_status = $dossier_status;

        return $this;
    }



}
```

The schema generated for a post

```
{
  "title": "string",
  "status": 0,
  "fase": "string",
  "type": "string",
  "createdAt": "2023-03-22T10:17:02.147Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-03-22T10:17:02.147Z",
  "deletedAt": "2023-03-22T10:17:02.147Z",
  "dossierStatus": "string"
}
```

What i want

```
{ 
    "title" : "Sample Dossier",
  "status": 1,
 " fase_title": "AdviesLijn",
  "fase_status": 1,
  "type_title": "Rijbewijs",
  "type_status": 1,
  "dossier_status_title": "Wachten Op Document",
  "dossier_status": 1,
    "createdAt": "2023-03-22T09:53:53.753Z"
}
```

Comment: You can use a DTO and modify there all the properties and add additional: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/